# SCRIPT1014 and SCRIPT1002 error in Angular4 application with IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11

My angular 4 application works in different browser perfectly. While running any Angular 4 application in Internet Explorer version 11, getting below two errors while launching the application:

```
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character
addScript.js (9,1)

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
main.bundle.js (52,1)
```

Please need any help to fix this issue. Thank you in advance.
Note: I have tried with shims solution with Angular 2 which did not work really, i.e. shims_for_IE. Please let me know if differently I need to handle it.
[image]

My current polyfill:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol'; 
import 'core-js/es6/object'; 
import 'core-js/es6/typed'; 
import 'core-js/es6/function'; 
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int'; 
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float'; 
import 'core-js/es6/number'; 
import 'core-js/es6/math'; 
import 'core-js/es6/string'; 
import 'core-js/es6/date'; 
import 'core-js/es6/array'; 
import 'core-js/es6/regexp'; 
import 'core-js/es6/map'; 
import 'core-js/es6/set'; 
import 'core-js/es6/reflect'; 
import 'core-js/es7/reflect'; 
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Comment: Any quick resolution will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To make `Angular` applications to work on every browser, you can use `Polyfill`.

When you are generating a project with `Angular-CLI`, it's already shipped with a file containing the necessary `polyfills`. You can find this file under the `src/polyfill.ts` name.

Just open this file and uncomment the line you need (they are well documented, they are describing for which browser this `polyfill` is needed), once it's done, build your project again, force your browser to run on `IE11+ Compatibility mode`, and you are ready to go.

Comment: My polyfills.ts file holds below lines. Please let me know if I should include or remove:
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/typed';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a SCRIPT1002: Syntax error main.bundle.js.

My polyfill.ts file was the same. I ended up editing the index.html file by adding a blank div, then saved the html file, then removed the div, and then saved it again. After saving the html file angular cli reloaded and it worked with IE11.